# Chapéus secretos no Winter Bash 2015

Tags: debate, winterbash-2015

Bom, como todos sabem (ou não), não existem apenas os chapéus que estão na [página do Winter Bash](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/).

Além deles, existem alguns chapéus que a forma de ganha-los é *secreta*.

Então, se você ganhou algum chapéu secreto, conte pra gente e faça o nível de 'quaker'.reverse() do pessoal ficar maior que 8000.

Comment: Para quem quiser ver o que foi descoberto e compartilhado na rede SE: [Winter Bash 2015 Secret Hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270789/229289)

Comment: It's over 9000!

Comment: Nessas traduções eles comeram 1000 unidades de força do Goku.  Kkkkk

Answer (score 11):

Já que ninguém se animou a responder aí vai uma, [trazida do meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270851/229289):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Ano passado tinha um chapéu secreto que se ganhava comentando em qualquer publicação da [abby hairboat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165581/abby-hairboat), uma ideia de chapéu dada por [Jon Ericson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1438/jon-ericson) para encher a caixa de notificações do Abby :P Esse ano Abby se vingou e fez um chapéu para quem comentasse em publicações do Jon. Não contam as publicações em metas filhos, apenas nos sites principais, incluindo o próprio [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Coitado do Jon `:D`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-shell-script/59871?noredirect=1#comment56448358_59871

Comment: @JorgeB. boa :D

Comment: Consegui ganhar esse tambem.

Comment: Ganhei um chapéu secreto porém não tenho a mínima ideia de como consegui, há um modo de descobri como ? (este chapéu azul simples que estou usando)

Comment: @Ricardo no momento não há como ter certeza, mas ao final da edição eles revelam com detalhes o que tinha que ser feito para conseguir cada chapéu. Em todo o caso você sempre pode ver as especulações aqui: [Winter Bash 2015 Secret Hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats) ou na nossa versão em Português aqui nesse tópico mesmo.

Answer (score 6):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## 007

> Você precisa postar uma resposta com 0 comentários* em uma questão com 0 comentários* e pegar 7 upvotes. 
>
>
>   <sup>*Comentários excluídos também contam</sup>

Comment: Fiz uma edição se não concordar pode reverter.

Comment: @Jorge, está certo. Obrigado. Meu português é muito ruim.

Comment: Como que faz esse hover?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe olha  [destruidores](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#spoilers).

Comment: @DiegoFelipe basta por isto antes do texto: `>! `

Comment: @user980828 Seu português deve ser melhor do que o de quem traduziu "spoilers" como "destruidores" :P

Comment: Pelo menos não traduziram "spoiler" para "aerofólio"

Answer (score 6):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Flip Flop

> Existem duas variações, branco e azul. A melhor teoria atualmente é que você ganha este chapéu para sua primeira ação em 21 de dezembro.

Fonte: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271127

Comment: É verdade, eu ganhei o meu assim.

Comment: Notar que são as cores do vestido misterioso. É dourado e branco, ou azul e preto?

Comment: ???  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgqOEsX74T0 O que? Que vestido? lol @Bacco

Comment: @gustavox https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4dXajUmj5C0

Comment: ahuhauhuauha eu lembro disso! kkkkkk @Bacco

Answer (score 4):

### Odinson

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Fechar ou sinalizar um post como duplicata antes dele ser fechado por usuário com a "gold badge" (acho que é a medalha de tag ouro). O  usuário com a medalha que fechar uma pergunta que já têm votos para fechamento também ganha o chapéu (conforme explicado pelo bfavaretto nos comentários).

[Fonte](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271127)

Comment: A segunda parte diz que o usuário com a medalha que fechar uma pergunta que já têm votos de fechamento também ganha o chapéu.